# How to get the logged in user's email address with Yahoo Contacts API?

Tags: oauth, contacts, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I managed to log a user in using OAuth. Then I can retrieve all the user's contacts by calling http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts?format=json&count=max.

But I can't find a way to get the **user's own email address**. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using OpenID+OAuth in order to get the user's info with OpenID and the user's contacts with OAuth:
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/openid-oauth-guide.html

Comment: can you tell me how to did that i am also looking for a way as i am able to get user profile except his/her email id

Comment: Just follow the steps here: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/openid-oauth-guide.html - You can get the email address from the OpenID login and then use OAuth to get the Contacts.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm, I tried to make openId request as per doc. I am getting error. Can you have look at my question and help me to resolve this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799043/error-connecting-with-yahoo-openid

Comment: @rajeevprasanna, sorry, I'm not using this anymore, so I don't know if it's still working. They might have deprecated it.