# Error connecting with yahoo openId

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

When i make the following request as mentioned in [yahoo open id doc spec](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/request-token.html), i am getting error : **Sorry! You will not be able to link your Yahoo account with this website or application. It is using an older version of the OpenID technology**.

Request i am making is : 
https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth? openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select &openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select &openid.mode=checkid_setup &openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0 &openid.realm=http://ec2-54-200-227-210.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ &openid.return_to=http://ec2-54-200-227-210.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ &openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0 &openid.oauth.consumer=consumer_key

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?? . I am trying to implement yahoo mail access with oauth but could not succeeded. Getting the same error.